# Is there a way to bypass ESQL & use own sql generation?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

From what I understood, EF LINQ generates ESQL & corresponding SQL driver will translate ESQL to target SQL. In this case it looks as two step process & it is very restricted as well. No way to easily call any custom SQL command.

All features of EF are nice, I would like to bypass ESQL & generate target SQL from LINQ.

Is it possible with EF6 custom providers? Or am I left to reinvent the wheel & write entirely new framework?

I am not asking about literal SQL, I am talking about IQueryable materialising into an Entity.

Comment: "No way to easily call any custom SQL command" - are you sure? I am pretty sure I saw example in the Internetz that demonstrated custom stored proc used in LINGTOSQL, with very little effort.

Comment: Wrapping things in stored procedure is itself complicated & restricted. I want Func<s,a,b> to translate to s(a,b) as literal and a, b should be Passed as Command Parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not correct. EF does not translate Linq to ESQL. Rather than it creates a [DbCommandTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.commandtrees.dbcommandtree%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is passed to the provider to translate to Sql. Having said that the Linq expression tree is currently not publically accessible. This is being tracked [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/104) - feel free to upvote this work item.

Note that the DbCommandTree that is passed to a provider is more suited to translate to SQL since it takes care of a few things like "flattening" types (i.e. getting rid of complex types) or translating types that don't exist in the DB (e.g. enums) to an equivalent the Db can understand. Another goal of the processing is to prepare materialization for the results to entities. I don't think you would be able to use EF just by translating the Linq expression to SQL (somehow). For me it sounds like you just need to create a linq provider that can translate Linq to Sql queries and commands you don't need the whole EF baggage. If this is what you are after you should look at Matt Warren's [Building a LINQ IQueryable provider series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2009/06/16/building-a-linq-iqueryable-provider-part-xv-iqtoolkit-v0-15.aspx) who shows how to do that.

Comment: Is there anyway to intercept DbCommandTree and inject something into it?

Comment: Before EF6 you would have to wrap the provider (there is toolkit/sample that can help with this http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32, in EF6 you can use IDbCommandTreeInterceptor)

Comment: Can you give me little more detail about IDbCommandTreeInterceptor? Some example would be nice.

Comment: You can read more about interceptors here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464#BuildingBlocks. To add an interceptor you need create a configuration class derived from the DbConfiguration class and call AddInterceptor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbconfiguration.addinterceptor(v=vs.113).aspx passing the an object implementing one of the interceptor interfaces.

Comment: I already read that, but it is about IDbCommandInterceptor, not about IDbCommandTreeInterceptor

Comment: Not sure whether it makes any difference - the general mechanism of registering and using all the interceptors is the same. The difference is when the interceptor's methods are invoked but the methods on the interfaces should make it clear. I guess, I am asking what information you are missing...

Answer (score 1):

If you access your context you can write straight SQL against the Connection like this.

```
var selectSomeData = Context.Databas.SqlQuery<string>("select * from foo").ToList();
```

here is some reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

Comment: In what way this translates LINQ to SQL?

Comment: @Akash Kava.  Your right it does not directly translate LINQ to SQL but with a little bit of additional thought a simple repository pattern on your entities would allow you to return an IQuerable from your repository and utilize this IQueryable to generate LINQ to Object statements from the repository.   However there is another option which would be to map a stored procedure in EF. https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Insert%2FUpdate%2FDelete%20Stored%20Procedure%20Mapping  Not exactly accomplish what you want, but can be manipulated for something similar.